# How to get label of checked inupt in css

Tags: css, django

How can I change the background-color of the label from a checked radio button.
Django renders form radio inputs like this:

```
<label for="id_form-level_0">
  <input type="radio" name="form-level" value="1" required="" id="id_form-level_0">
  description 
</label>
```

I dont have the intention to change this, so the most commun solution

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

does not work. In addition the :has() selector seems not to be supported in the browsers, meaning the following code neither works.

```
label:has(input[type="radio"]:checked) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

What is the correct way to adress the right label in css?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, css3 can *not* follow references to other elements. So this will require some JS that also manipulates the label itself.

Comment: You could add a label *after* the `input`, and then work with a direct sibling, as you found out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `:has` pseudoclass dont work proper in FireFox (https://caniuse.com/css-has).
This is impossible to select parent element in CSS.
It is unfortunate because you use `label` element as parent to `input`.

Answer (score 0):

if input checked, make inputs background red,

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
background:red;}
```

if inputs checked, make sibling labels background red. (label should come later than input )

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```